# Image is disappearing when using CSS's transform

Tags: css

Recently I've been facing a problem that whenever I try to use transform with a certain image, it just goes blank. The picture below (before transform):

Also, this is the information of the file:

[image]

CSS:

```css
[id^=addition] {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 45%;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 15px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    line-height: 55px;
    vertical-align: top;
    transition: box-shadow 0.4s, filter 0.5s, transform 0.3s;
    background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/gLLYdU/bottom_buttons_min.png);
    background-size: 19199px 75px;
}

[id^=addition]:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1)
}
```

```html
<div id=addition_example> </div>
```

some JS code that splits the big file into pieces:

```
$('#addition_' + additions[i] + ', #addition_search_' + additions[i] + ', #addition_category_' + additions[i] + ', #addition_colorizing_' + additions[i]).css({
       'background-size': additions_buttons_scale[$.inArray(additions_type[i], addition_type_symbol)][1] * 69 + 'px 69px',
     'background-position': -69 * random_number + 'px',
     'background-color': 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'
 })
```

Comment: It's near impossible to reproduce your problem with info you've supplied. Use the snippet or a sandbox, such as codepen to create a live demo of your problem. If you can't, add the markup, all relevant CSS, and and a link to original PNG.

Comment: Can you show us styles which are used? It looks like you have long image of images (like many images in one image) so you are using it as a image-background with positions - and you are using scale - it ruins your scales.

Comment: @icecoder - store the image in a cloud service, and use the link.

Comment: done that, file isn't uploading @OriDrori

Comment: Can someone please help me change the body's background to grey, the button can't be seen.